# Append an element after other

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I want to select an element and append this after other:

Using this dont work:

```
$('.sub'+$(this).val()).appendTo($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent());
```

the dom is:

```
<div class="sub1"></div>


<label></label>
```

Expect this:

```
<label></label>
<div class="sub1"></div>
```

the really dom:

http://pastebin.com/6Vd6USEp

the task is append the div after the label, i search this label per a input.subN and pick de parentparentparentparentparent

Comment: Try this.val() without the brackets and $ symbol.

Comment: Need way more information.  What is "this" in the context.  Why parent()x4?  What's the whole DOM tree look like?  Gotta give us more details.  Are you just swapping the order of the label and the div?  Why?

Comment: If the elements need to stay at the same level, then `.parent().parent().parent().parent()` is not what you want. The DOM looks incomplete.

Comment: tryed using after() but dont work too :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about what you're trying to do, but here goes:
If you need to simply move the label to be before the div, do this:

```
$("label").remove().insertBefore(".sub1");​
```

If you need to move the div to be after label, do this:

```
$(".sub1").remove().insertAfter("label");​
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/QpP9J/

Comment: Note that you don't need `.remove()` when moving elements.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to add your label before the other element, use prepend. http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 1):

You need **[before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)**.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/QTaHg/)**

```
$('.sub1').before('<label></label>');
```